# Get values from a multi-value combo box in access vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form that I'm using to gather information that will be inserted into a database table in Access 2016. My form has a multi-value combo box (called cmbContacts) that pulls values from a Contacts table (ID and Name). A user is able to select 0 or more contacts from the combo box. When a user clicks the submit button, the button_click event triggers VBA code to format the information and insert it into the table.

What I need to do is get the IDs of each selected contact from the combo box.

Here's what I have so far:

```
If Me.cmbContacts.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then 'Only run code if there are contacts selected'
    'Select the most recently added entry (added right before this if statement)'
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, Max As Integer
    SQL = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Breweries"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
    Max = rs.Fields(0)
    'Insert each selected Contact ID into Breweries.[Contact Names].Value'
    Dim itm As Variant
    For Each itm In Me.cmbContacts.ItemsSelected
        SQL = "INSERT INTO Breweries ([Contact Names].[Value]) VALUES (" + itm + ") WHERE ID=" + Max
        CurrentDb.Execute (SQL)
    Next itm
End If
```

Some issues:

- Me.cmbContacts.ItemsSelected.Count always equals 0, regardless of how many items are selected in the Combo Box
- Because cmbContacts.ItemsSelected doesn't contain the selected items, the for loop doesn't run. I'm not sure why it's not registering the selected items

Comment: I am not quite sure why you are working with the Max. You do not need the Where part in the SQL-statement.
SQL = "INSERT INTO Breweries ([Contact Names].[Value]) VALUES (" + itm + ") ".
Why are you labling a combobox with txt as suffix which points to a textbox?

Comment: I do need the Max - it gives me the ID of the most recently added entry into the Breweries Table. I then add values into the "Contact Names" field of the entity with that ID.

I can update my code so that the _prefix_ better aligns with the object

Comment: Multi-select combo boxes must be new in MSA16. Or are you using a Listbox?

Comment: No, I'm using a multi-select combo box, like the left side of this image
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/MultiSelComboBox/image001.png

Comment: I think that control is for a web page - which control are you actually using on your Access form?

Comment: @jhTuppeny Here is an image of the form that I'm working on. You can see in the Property Sheet that it is in fact a Combo Box. The second image is the same field in use - you can see it is a drop down Combo Box with check boxes to allow for multiple selections.
http://imgur.com/GcdO1EY
http://imgur.com/m8M1Tu0

Comment: The issues that you are having are to do with the specific properties of the control that you're using. You need to specify exactly which custom control you've used to be sure how to work with it. The standard combo box control that comes with Access doesn't have check boxes and buttons.

Comment: @estoner: it looks like you are talking about Silverlight not Access. There is no such Combo Box in MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

If a combobox has more than 1 item selected/populated, then you can use Ubound() to find out how many.

```
IF UBound(Me.cmbContacts.OldValue) > 0
    For i = LBound(Me.cmbContacts.OldValue) To UBound(Me.cmbContacts.OldValue)
       SQL = "INSERT INTO Breweries ([Contact Names].[Value]) VALUES (" + Me.cmbContacts.OldValue(i) + ") WHERE ID=" + Max
        CurrentDb.Execute (SQL)
    Next i
END IF
```

Bear in mind this will error with a Type Mismatch if only one, or no values are selected and you will have to handle this somehow.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching on MVF's and VBA all I found was working with parent/child recordsource. In my case the user has selected the values but they are not saved to the table yet. I just needed a way to loop through the control and get all the values selected. Couldn't find this anywhere - in case it's helpful to someone.

```
 For Each Val in me.MultiValueComboBoxName.Value
    'Do Action
 Next
```